# Conda remove all environments (except root)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I know I can delete a single environment with

```
 conda remove -n envname --all
```

but I often create multiple new environments for installing a specifiy package or testing it so I'll regularly end up with 5-10 environments and it's a pain to delete them after one another. Is there an easy way (for windows) to delete all environments except the root-environment?

Comment: Maybe you can try something like `conda info --envs` and grab the list of environments and create a loop through that list with like `conda remove --name envname --all`. Obviously you would need to avoid your root environment.

Comment: @Ringil - If there is no "convenience option" for what I'm looking do you have any idea how to do that grab and put option with windows?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Removing all directories inside the `envs` subdirectory that resides inside `conda` does the job. This is generally in your user folder `~`.

```
~\.conda\envs\
```

Comment: Although in practice a minor risk, deleting the environment folder will fail to run any pre-unlink scripts, which some packages use to clean up user- or system-level settings they configure at install time (e.g., unsubscribing from event hooks). Using `conda env remove` should be regarded as better practice.

Answer (score 24):

Mac/Linux based systems could remove all environments like this.

```bash
for environment_name in $(conda env list | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v -e '^base' -e '^#' | tr '\n' ' ')
do
    echo "$environment_name"
    conda remove --name "$environment_name"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Not the most elegant answer. But I would just copy the names of all the environments from `conda info --envs`. Then make a bash (or .bat for windows) file with all the commands you need e.g...

```
conda remove -n env_name_1 --all -y
conda remove -n env_name_2 --all -y
conda remove -n env_name_3 --all -y
conda remove -n env_name_4 --all -y
conda remove -n env_name_5 --all -y
```

Or just copy and paste that into the terminal and it will sort you out!

If I was a little bash (or .bat) wizard (or could be bothered to do some googling) you could pipe the output from `conda info --envs` to generate the `conda remove ...` commands.

Comment: Apparently the edit queue is full for this answer so I can't edit it directly, but this didn't work for me until I prefixed every line with `CALL `

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment, you can get all the environments with one conda command and then try to loop through it and remove them individually. Here is one way you could do something like this. Note that you should replace `anaconda_command_prompt_string` with the appropriate string that your Anaconda Command Prompt calls. Also this code is probably quite fragile:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

anaconda_command_prompt_string = 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe "/K" C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3'
p = Popen(anaconda_command_prompt_string, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
p.stdout.readline(), # read the first line

print >>p.stdin, 'conda env list' # write input
p.stdin.flush() 
p.stdout.readline()

p.stdout.readline()

p.stdout.readline()

p.stdout.readline()
envs = []


line = 'Anaconda'
while 'Anaconda' in line:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    name = line.replace(' ', '').split('C:')[0]
    if 'root' not in name and '\n' not in name:
        envs.append(name)

for name in envs:
   command_string = 'conda remove -n {0} --all --yes'.format(name)
   print >>p.stdin, command_string
   p.stdin.flush()
   line = p.stdout.readline()
   while 'Complete' not in line:
      print line
      line = p.stdout.readline()
   print line
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as satisfying as if conda had a built-in tool to do this (which it may), but you can delete the entire environment folder and recreate it in two lines.

```
rm -Rf /path/to/env_dir/envs/
mkdir /path/to/env_dir/envs/
```

Use `conda info --envs` or `condo env list` to find the path to your environments:

```
$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /path/to/env_dir/
my_env                   /path/to/env_dir/envs/my_env
my_env_somewhere_else    /other/path/to/env_dir/envs/my_env_somewhere_else
```

Note, you may have environments in more than one location, so you may need to delete more than one directory, but they should show up in your list of environments.